# C++ Sorting an Array in Alphabetical order using strcpy and strcmp while taking data from a file?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, string-function

I almost have it working however, it is seperating the last names that start in caps and the ones that do not.

Example file

LastName FirstName DaysofRental BalanceDue

Smith Joe 15 100.50

Doe John 10 95.20

Anderson Paul 30 20.00

O'Donell Miriam 10 24.30

Foster Sam 30 15.00

Zom Pete 10 20.00

Mock Chilly 100 30

smitty Chris 200 200

xu Conor 1 200

anilo steve 0 0

What "Sorted" file is outputing

LastName            FirstName           DaysofRental        BalanceDue

Anderson            Paul                30                  $20.00

Doe                 John                10                  $95.20

Foster              Sam                 30                  $15.00

Mock                Chilly              100                 $30.00

O'Donell            Miriam              10                  $24.30

Smith               Joe                 15                  $100.50

Zom                 Pete                10                  $20.00

**anilo               steve               0                   $0.00

smitty              Chris               200                 $200.00

xu                  Conor               1                   $200.00**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>  
using namespace std;
const int STRINGSIZE = 30;
const int LISTSIZE  = 10;
const int HEADSIZE = 4;

typedef char STRING30[STRINGSIZE];
typedef STRING30 NAMES[LISTSIZE];

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("sorted.txt");

int count, 
    count2,
    mindex;

int rdays[LISTSIZE],
    hrdays;

double baldue[LISTSIZE],
       totalbaldue, 
       hbaldue, 
       tempnum;

NAMES first, 
      last, 
      header;

STRING30 mname, 
         tempname;  

ifstream in;
in.open("invoice1_test1.txt");

//Input Section

if(in.is_open())
{
    in >> header[0]
       >> header[1] 
       >> header[2] 
       >> header[3]; 

    int count = 0;

    while(!in.eof())
    {
        in >> last [count] 
           >> first[count]
           >> rdays[count]
           >> baldue[count];
        count++;
    }
    in.close();     
}

else 

{
    cout << "File failed to open" << endl;
}

    for(count = 0; count < LISTSIZE; count++)
{
    mindex = count;
    strcpy(mname, last[count]);
    for(count2 = count; count2 < LISTSIZE; count2++)
    {
        if(strcmp(last[count2], mname) == -1)
        {
            mindex = count2;
            strcpy(mname, last[count2]);
        }
    }

    strcpy(tempname, last[count]);
    strcpy(last[count], mname);
    strcpy(last[mindex], tempname);

    strcpy(tempname, first[count]);
    strcpy(first[count], first[mindex]);
    strcpy(first[mindex], tempname);

    tempnum = rdays[count];
    rdays[count]= rdays[mindex];
    rdays[mindex]= tempnum;

    tempnum = baldue[count];
    baldue[count] = baldue[mindex];
    baldue[mindex] = tempnum;
}
outfile << setiosflags(ios::showpoint | ios::fixed) << setprecision(2);

outfile << left << setw(20) << header[0] << setw(20) << header[1] << setw(20) << header[2] << setw(20) << header[3] << endl;

for(int count = 0; count<LISTSIZE; count++)
{
    outfile << left << setw(20) << last[count] << setw(20) << first[count] << setw(20) << rdays[count] << "$" << setw(20) << baldue[count] << endl;
}
```

Comment: This is C++. Why are you sticking to `strcpy` and `strcmp` instead of `std::string`? Why are you not using `std::sort` or `std::stable_sort`? If this is homework, what other restrictions are you operating under?

Comment: Professor wants it to be done using string compare and string copy, I wouldn't know how to answer what other restrictions. But we can only use the string functions we learned in class.

Comment: And that's how you teach ugly C/C++ mix... At least can we warn you against using [`while(!in.eof())`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) and [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)?

Comment: He's already warned us about `using namespace std; ` but since it's a beginner course I think he did it to make it easier on us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `if (strcmpi(last[count2], mname)  < 0);` for the comparison, instead of `if (strcmp(last[count2], mname)  ==-1);`

`strcmpi()` functions same as `strcmp()` but it is not case sensitive.

Also add `exit(1)` if `ifstream in` fails to open.

Answer (score 0):

Convert all names to uppercase before storing.

Comment: I would not know how to do that.

Comment: Look at [toupper()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper), which will convert one character at a time. Looking at your data, I think you need merely convert the first letter in the last name. Or, you could convert the entire array, but you'd also have to convert back. Depends on whether they want "erroneous" information kept that way.